# Dynamic CSS loading using variable in jinja

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a variable `UI_BRAND` that has the value of `blue`

I have the following code:

```
{% if UI_BRAND != 'default' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='UI_BRAND-styles.css') }}">
{% endif %}
```

I need `UI_BRAND-styles.css` to evaluate to `blue-styles.css`. I've tried using `{{}}` inside if the already existing brackets, but  I know that's not allowed.

What would be the best way to dynamically load this CSS file using the value of `UI_BRAND` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about assigning the filename in the previous line. I thinks it's also easier to read:

```
{% if UI_BRAND != 'default' %}
  <% set style_filename = UI_BRAND + '-styles.css' %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=style_filename) }}">
{% endif %}
```

or you can use `+` in the same line with the variable and your string.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=UI_BRAND + '-styles.css') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems to be a good use case for f-strings. Maybe something like this?

```py
filename=f'{UI_BRAND}-styles.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='UI_BRAND-styles.css') }}">
```

Instead of that you can try this:

```
{% if UI_BRAND != 'default' %}
    <style src="{{ UI_BRAND }}-styles.css"></style>
{% endif %}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

---

#### N.B:

You may need to add static root before **{{ UI_BRAND }}** like this

```
<style src="static_root/{{ UI_BRAND }}-styles.css"></style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don Eitner is close.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename=UI_BRAND ~ '-styles.css') }}">
```

Concatenation in jinja involves the tilde (`~`).

So for `{"FOO": "a", "BAR": "b", "numbers": "1234" }`

```
FOO ~ BAR
```

Evaluates to "ab"

And:

```
{{ numbers | join(BAR ~ FOO ~ "n" ~ FOO ~ "n" ~ FOO) }}
```

Evaluates to "1banana2banana3banana4"

Here's a useful tool I validated this answer against: https://cryptic-cliffs-32040.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTED and tested. The following results in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/blue-styles.css">` in my testing.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='' ~ UI_BRAND ~ '-styles.css') }}">
```